# open cover and boundedness

Tags: general-topology

Use the open cover characterization of compactness to prove that if $f:[a,b]→X$ is a continuous function and $X$ is a metric space, the $f$ is bounded.

Proof:
To show $f$ is bounded we must show that $f([a,b])$ is a bounded subset of $X$. So if $f([a,b]) \subseteq X$ then $[a,b]$ is compact if and only if $[a,b]$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence of elements of $[a,b]$. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem $\{x_n\}$ contains a convergent sub-sequence with limit $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $[a,b]$ is closed, $x \in [a,b]$. Thus, $[a,b]$ is compact.

Now we must show $f([a,b])$ is compact in $X$.

Suppose $f$ is continuous and $X$ is a metric space. Let $\{U_{x}:x \in \mathscr{U} \}$ be an open cover of $f(Y)$ where $Y = [a,b]$. For each point $y \in Y$, $f(y) \in f(Y)$ so $f(y) \in U_{x_{y}}$ for some $x_{y} \in \mathscr{U}$, that is $y \in f^{-1}(U_{x_{y}})$.

Thus, the collection $\{f^{-1}(U_{x}): x \in \mathscr{U}$ is a cover of $Y$. Since $f$ is continuous each set $f^{-1}(U_{x})$ is open in $Y$, so $\{ 
f^{-1}(U_{x}):x \in \mathscr{U} \}$ is an open cover of $Y$.

Since $Y$ is compact, it has a finite subcover of 
$\{f^{-1}(U_{x_{}}),...f^{-1}(U_{x_{n}})\}$. Given $x \in f(Y)$, there exists $y\in Y$ such that $f(y)=x$, and $y \in f^{-1}(U_{x_{i}})$ for some $i$, 
so $x \in U_{x_{i}}$.

Thus, $\{U_{x},....,U_{x_{n}}\}$ is a finite subcover of $f(Y)$, so $f(Y)$ is compact. So by definition, since $f(Y)$ is compact then $f$ is bounded.

I was told this was right but I was missing how to show why $f(Y)$ is compact. Any ideas how to clear up what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems very complicated.

Let $y \in X$. The collection of balls $B(y,n)$ is an open cover of $X$. Hence $f^{-1}(B(y,n)\}$ forms an open cover of $[a,b]$ since $f$ is continuous. Since there must be a finite subcover, choose $n^*$ to be the largest $n$ in all the balls. Then $f(x) \in B(y,n^*)$ for all $x \in X$. Hence $f$ is bounded.

**Addendum**: To show why $f(Y)$ is compact:

Suppose $\{ U_\alpha \}$ is an open cover of $f(Y)$. Then $\{ f^{-1}(U_\alpha) \}$ is an open cover of $Y$ because $f$ is continuous (this is the key step here).

Since $Y$ is compact, there is a finite subcover $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha_1}),...,f^{-1}(U_{\alpha_n})$. That is, $Y = f^{-1}(U_{\alpha_1}) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(U_{\alpha_n})$. Hence $f(Y) \subset U_{\alpha_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{\alpha_n}$, that is, $U_{\alpha_1}, ..., U_{\alpha_n}$ is a finite cover of $f(Y)$.

Hence every open cover of $f(Y)$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: So just by saying that the image of the boundary of (y,n) is an open cover of the interval then f is bounded?

Comment: copper.hat, it appears @RuthGutierrez didn't appreciate why a continuous function carries compactness, rather than being confused as to why a compact set is necessarily bounded.

Comment: So I should focus more on the fact that the function is continuous?

Comment: @RuthGutierrez yes, but you've proved that proposition yourself, by taking an arbitrary cover for $f(Y)$ and finding a finite sub-cover.

Comment: I added some detail.

Comment: didn't i show that f(Y) has a finite subcover?

Comment: You did. Initially I was just showing that you can show that $f(Y)$ is bounded directly by taking the open cover of $X$ to be $B(y,n)$. (This is just the standard proof of why a compact subset of a metric space is bounded.)

Comment: Oh ok so really just by saying what you have in the first part it answers the question of $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, it shows that $f(Y)$ is bounded directly. Your proof has a lot of extraneous stuff. I don't really see what you are doing in Paragraphs 2, 3 & 4. Also, in Paragraph 8, it is not true that by definition $f(Y)$ is bounded. That is a consequence of the Heine–Borel theorem.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Well what I thought I had to do was to show [a,b] was compact and then show f([a,b]) was compact. I was going step by step but I didn't know I could go a different route on that. Thank you so much copper.hat